# Regular expression to match after last - (dash)

Tags: python, regex

Suggest a regular expression to match anything after last - (dash)

- Case 1

  `In [1]: a = 'abc - def - ghi'
  Out [2]: result = '- ghi'`

  - Case 2

  `In [1]: a = 'abc - def - ghi 2323'
  Out [2]: result = '- ghi 232'`

I have tried following regex

`-[\s|\w|\d]+)(?!.*\-)` 
but failed to get desire output in below case:
`Aaab, xyz, abc - Offer No. 18155`

Comment: what've you tried?

Comment: @appleapple I have tried ```-[\s|\w|\d]+)(?!.*\-)```

Comment: then put it into question. plus your fail example (input, output, regex). better a [mcve]

Comment: Will you accept a non regex solution?

Comment: @theausome thanks but I only need regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `-[^-]*(?!.*-)`

---

In: `abc - def - ghi`
Match 1: `- ghi`

In: `abc - def - ghi 2323`
Match 1: `- ghi 2323`

Answer (score 2):

you can match the end use `$`

full regex: `-[^-]*$`

---

in case you do not need to use regex

you can simply use `'-'+str.split('-')[-1]`

Comment: Upps you were a little bit faster :3

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
-[^-]*$
```

Works for both of your examples

Answer (score 0):

An easy non `regex` solution:

```
a = 'abc - def - ghi'
print('-{}'.format(a.rsplit('-', 1)[1]))
# - ghi
```

Comment: Fine. This might help someone in future.